# Cropping a JPEG in Photoshop CS2

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I need to crop this .jpeg image:
[image]

in Photoshop CS2 to a vertical 1px image so I can repeatedly render it horizontally to create the full gradients that are dynamically sized.

Do you know how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Single column marquee tool` found under (by default) the regular `Rectangular marquee tool` in the toolbar to select 1 px wide and *"image height"* high area. <sup>[1]</sup>

Then choose `Image` → `Crop`

---

[1]: `Single row marguee tool` works in a similar fashion. It selects an area that is 1 px high and *"image width"* wide.

Comment: that small print really is small print

Comment: @Jaips it's a feature not a bug ;-) well, I removed the <sup>-tags. Apparently the `'s prevent markdown from treating the line as a link-reference after all.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Image -> Canvas Size..., change the units to pixels, and change the width to 1 px. Photoshop will yell at you about the new dimensions being smaller than the original; click the "Yes" button.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom to the maximum, such as 3200%, and it will show you the 1 pixel of the image. Then crop it from anywhere you want.